# Python Global Hotkey

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

I'm looking to create a global hotkey in **Python 3.2** for **Ubuntu 12.10**. That is, my script will run in the background and whenever I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (for example), no matter what the active window is, the script will do something.

These http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=J4swvcgD are the `resources` I've looked at (had to paste them in Pastebin since Stack Overflow only allows me to post two links)

Maybe I am too much of a newb (I am a beginner) or I have been looking in the wrong places or for the wrong things, but, I haven't been able to utilize the resources above.

How can I create a global hotkey with **Python 3.2** in **Ubuntu 12.10**. Thanks!

ps: This is a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/229129/python-global-hotkey

Comment: https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/engla/keybinder; it's a simple library that proclaims to enable global keyboard shortcuts and includes Python bindings.  It's specific to GTK, but if your target is Ubuntu *most* Ubuntu systems are using Gnome and GTK-based applications by default.  YMMV outside of GTK windows, in which case you'll have to use some lower-level X11 calls.

Comment: it took a bit of compiling, but I just ran one of the examples! Very neat!! Thank you!